# Cannot delete non-existing table space

Tags: mysql

When dropping a schema, it sometimes happens that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.files are not updated for a table.

```sql
select * from information_schema.innodb_sys_tablespaces where name like '%#sql%';
```

| SPACE | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 539548 | tmp/#sql650_929_d |
| 539553 | tmp/#sql650_90e_e |
| 539557 | tmp/#sql650_928_12 |
| 539559 | tmp/#sql650_910_15 |
| 539563 | tmp/#sql650_92b_12 |

```sql
select * from information_schema.innodb_sys_datafiles where path like '%#sql%';
```

| SPACE | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| 539548 | /tmp/#sql650_929_d.ibd |
| 539553 | /tmp/#sql650_90e_e.ibd |
| 539557 | /tmp/#sql650_928_12.ibd |
| 539559 | /tmp/#sql650_910_15.ibd |
| 539563 | /tmp/#sql650_92b_12.ibd |
| 539570 | /tmp/#sql650_90f_13.ibd |
| 539578 | /tmp/#sql650_90c_18.ibd |
| 539581 | /tmp/#sql650_914_15.ibd |
| 539582 | /tmp/#sql650_913_1b.ibd |
| 539587 | /tmp/#sql650_912_18.ibd |
| 539588 | /tmp/#sql650_90d_1b.ibd |
| 539590 | /tmp/#sql650_926_15.ibd |

```sql
DROP TABLESPACE `tmp/#sql650_929_d`;
```

```
ERROR 3119 (42000): InnoDB: A general tablespace name cannot contain '/'.
```

how can i delete the tablespace?

Comment: Is there a question or are you just telling us?

Comment: how can i delete the tablespace?